# python: how to extract the consecutive slice with different length in string without a space

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example, in a string which is `789101112`,

```
i = 1 
j = 0 
x = '789101112'  
while i < 3:
    while j < len(x):
        m = int(x[j: j+i])
        n = int(x[j+i: j+i+i])
        if n - m ==1:
            print(m, n)
            j +=i
```

The output is:

```
7 8
8 9
```

The output I want is:

```
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 11
11 12
```

What should I need to do based on my codes?

Comment: is the string guaranteed to have increasing order of numbers? if not we'll need some sort of separator in between the numbers

Comment: Yes, the string have to be in increasing order . I just don't know how to do when the case comes to 9 and 10

Comment: when the input is 891089118912, the output is 8910, 8911, 8912 right?

Comment: and what would be the max and min (the range) of numbers? here in your case it is 7 to 12 so what would be the max and min?

Comment: @user5802211, can we consider that string as a range of numbers, not as string?

Comment: no, the input is like 789101112, the output is 7 8 9 10 11 12  or another case is 979899100101102, and I want to get the consecutive slice like 97 98 99 100 101 102

Comment: it's pretty complex case, cause you should know in advance which sequence starts from two-digit number and which - from single-digit number

Comment: @user5802211 you should work with range of numbers, not with string

Comment: Let's go a step back: why do you have a string like that? That makes no sense. Where does it come from?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, that's the problem I got stuck. Regard iit as  numbers is not allowwed, if it is numbers, it would be easy, we just +=1 each time, but I want to separate this string into slice with increasing order

Comment: @user5802211, are you sure that the string format is the only one input format and there's no chances to work with a range?

Comment: @zvone it is just one case I need to realize in my long codes. 7 8 9 10 11 12 is simple case I list in order to make my question clear. I need to separate 9798100101102  into slices 97 98 100 101 102 in order to detect the missing number 99. in this case, I got stuck in how to know  which sequence starts from two digit number and which from three digit number.

Comment: @user5802211 I understand, but I believe the solution should be implemented at an earlier step. That is why I am asking why you have that kind of an input at all. Furthermore, if numbers can be missing, I am not sure there is only one solution to this problem in the general case.

Comment: @user5802211 so you want to slice the string to find the missing number(s)? if yes, can you tell me the **maximum count of consecutive missing numbers** that are allowed?? say for eg: 98 101  102 has 2 missing numbers and 7 11 12 has 3 missing numbers so what is the maximum count of missing consecutive numbers?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest format conversion is possible, my original purpose is to  separate 9798100101102 into slices 97 98 100 101 102 in order to detect the missing number 99. in this case, I got stuck in how to know which sequence starts from two digit number and which from three digit number.

Comment: @ritesht93  there is no maximum count of consecutive missing numbers, only need to detect the missing numbers.

Comment: @user5802211 so according to your statement, you can even have a sequence like 98 1025 1026 ..right? and you'd want to detect the missing numbers 99 to 1024? I think it would be doable if you can atleast tell us the maximum count of missing consecutive numbers?

Comment: @ritesht93 Yes, it could be, but the problem is that not necessary to set such a lage interval. the missing number can be one. That maybe easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of rough idea on the algorithm but I guess it took a bit more time than I anticipated to write a sample program.

Note: I have assumed the **maximum count of missing consecutive numbers** in the series to be 1. You can modify the code and apply a loop for maximum count as infinite or any other number you would prefer.

Its past midnight here so the code is not thoroughly tested. Here it is:

```
def get_first_num(string):
    first_num=0
    for i in range(int(len(string)/2)):
        if string.startswith(string[0:i+1]+str(int(string[0:i+1])+1)) or string.startswith(string[0:i+1]+str(int(string[0:i+1])+2)):    #max difference between any 2 consecutive numbers must be 1 or 2 i.e only 1 missing number in sequence is allowed
            assumed_first_num, temp, count, flag=int(string[0:i+1]), string, 0, False

            temp=temp.replace(str(assumed_first_num), '', 1)
            count += 1

            for _ in range(100):
                changed = False
                if(temp.startswith(str(assumed_first_num+1)) or temp.startswith(str(assumed_first_num+2))):
                    next_assumed_first_num=assumed_first_num+1 if temp.startswith(str(assumed_first_num+1)) else assumed_first_num+2
                    temp=temp.replace((str(assumed_first_num+1) if temp.startswith(str(assumed_first_num+1)) else str(assumed_first_num+2)), '', 1)
                    assumed_first_num, changed, count=next_assumed_first_num, True, count+1
                if len(temp) == 0:
                    flag=True
                    break
                if not changed:
                    flag=False
                    break
            if(flag):
                first_num=int(string[0:i+1])
                break
            else:
                continue
    return first_num

test_strings=["789101112", "910111213", "91112131415", "1214161820", "891089118912", "890892893894", "123451234712348", "1234567123456812345691234570"]
for string in test_strings:
    print("First number "+str(get_first_num(string))+" determined from string: "+string)
```

And the output for the above program is:

```
$ python3 script.py 
First number 7 determined from string: 789101112
First number 9 determined from string: 910111213
First number 9 determined from string: 91112131415
First number 12 determined from string: 1214161820
First number 8910 determined from string: 891089118912
First number 890 determined from string: 890892893894
First number 12345 determined from string: 123451234712348
First number 1234567 determined from string: 1234567123456812345691234570
```

The main challenge and tricky part in the problem was to determine the 1st number in the series; so as of now I have written only the function to determine the first number. I will be going to bed now, but I will extend the program to determine the missing numbers in the sequence which shouldn't take much time compared to this.

Also the **100** in the innermost for loop and the `count` for that loop literally counts the consistency of the given series with a maximum of 100 elements taken as sample which are guaranteed to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is the last line `j+=i`, `i` was never incremented! So it would always be 1. Also, when during the sequence, say from 9 to 10, it becomes 2 digits all of a sudden, then you also need to provision the next digit to see if it is still alright.

since the sequence is garanteed to be incremented by one, this alternative code might be a lazy solution:

```
def start_seq(num_str):
    '''determines the number the sequence starts with (minimum 3 numbers
    inside sequence)'''
    for i in range(1,len(num_str)//3):
        num1 = int(num_str[0:i])
        num2 = num1 + 1
        num3 = num2 + 1
        seq = str(num1)+str(num2)+str(num3)
        if num_str.startswith(seq):
            return num1
        else:
            continue
    return -1

def output_sequence(num_str):
    num1 = start_seq(num_str)
    if num1 == -1:            
        print('not a valid sequence')
        raise ValueError

    processed_seq = str(num1)

    counter = 0 # for printing '\n'
    #continue until reaching the end of sequence.
    while processed_seq !=num_str:
        print(num1,end=' ')
        if counter%2 == 1:
            print('\n',end='')
        num1 += 1
        processed_seq += str(num1)
        counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output_sequence('789101112')
```

Comment: your code is limited by the `range(1,100)` statement specified at line 3. For larger numbers say 12345671234568 it would unnecessarily evaluate till 1234567 even after you increase the range to `(1, 10000000)`

Comment: Hi ritesht93, you are right, that was kind of sloppy. I modified it, hopefully this would be more robust. The reason I am doing it this way is to try to avoid regular expression, so that it can hopefully gain a little speed.

Comment: uhmm well regex wouldn't be needed since we are just matching the string sequence incrementally from left to right. I removed my regex usage as well using a simple `replace()` function